# success function in ajax in django

Tags: django, jquery, django-views

in views:

```
return render_to_response("main.html", RequestContext(request, {'form':form, "result":result}))
```

in template i have this jquery function:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataPosted = $("#mainSubmit").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataPosted,
                url: 'main/',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#mainDiv").html(data);
                    $(".response").html({{ result }});
                    $(".response").show();
                }
            });
        });
    });

<div id="mainDiv" class="part">
    <form id="mainSubmit" action="main/" method="POST" name="submitForm">
        {% csrf_token %}       
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
        <div class="response"  style="display: none;"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

but it seems that data can't be assigned to response div like this(it seems data is not defined). So i don't know what is the way to send data to template. if i use `Httpresponse(result)` in views, then i can't have my form refreshed, and only i can display in response div data i send from view. so what is the way?

EDIT:
This is my views. before, i didn't put else for the condition if form.is_valid(): , but here i use, because i think if i don't do this, it might cause some probables. i don't know what is the best way.

```
def mainFunc(request):
    if request.is_ajax():        
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = mainForm(request.POST)
              if form.is_valid():             
                 // process the form     
                 result = "successful"
                 to_json = {'form':form, 'result':result}
                 return HttpResponse(json.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
              else:
                  result = ""
                  to_json = {'form':form, 'result':result}
                  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            form = mainForm()
            return render_to_response('main.html', RequestContext(request, {'form':form}))
    else:
        return render_to_response("ajax.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail. The first code example is from views.py, but it looks to be the view that renders the whole page. Where is the method that responds to the form's POST action? Is that the same? Also, the action is 'main/'. That's no absolute URL. Aren't you ending up with 'main/main/main/' URLs? Is there any data coming back at all from the form submit? (Hint: use firebug or something like that)

Comment: That can't work: `$(".response").html({{ result }});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a response in format like JSON

You can use [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/154/) or more simple code like this:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
to_json = {'form':form, "result":result}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Then you will be able to use `data.result` and `data.form` in your JS code.

If you use the same view for ajax and non-ajax call you can check for it with `request.is_ajax()`

Also you will not be able to use template tags and filters in your JS callback. So you need to pre-render your form before sending it via JSON

So the final code:

```
to_json = {'form':form, "result":result}
if request.is_ajax():
    to_json['form'] = to_json['form'].as_p()
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
else:
    render_to_response("main.html", RequestContext(request, {'form':form, "result":result}))
```

**Edit** I assume that `ajax.html` is the template for the whole page and `main.html` is the template for `mainDiv` part of the page

So in `is_ajax()` part of you view you can return the data like this.

```
to_json = {}
to_json['form'] = render_to_string('main.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
to_json['result'] = result
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

And you always return data like this, both for GET and POST AJAX calls

And in JS you get data like this:

```
$("#mainDiv").html(data.form);
$(".response").html(data.result);
$(".response").show();
```

Comment: Thank you. sorry, i never used json before, i used this code, but nothing happend. i edited my question. I need to show form errors when form is not valid and i want to know exactly in this case, what i should do. use HttpResponse or render_to_response, because i think in both case (form valid and form not valid) jquery success function is executed and only in the first time that the page is loading and method is not post, i should use render_to_response.is this true?

Comment: Should i use mimetype='application/json'? when? if i don't what's wrong? sorry i'm new in web programming, reallt thanks for your help :)

Comment: `render_to_response` is a shortcut and it returns the `HttpResponse` object too. JSON is format of data serialization, correct mimetype will make JQuery to parse it automatically. Actually it's not necessary to return JSON to ajax calls, you can return html or plain text, or XML... However it is easier for you if your view returns responses in single format.